# When Does It Make Sense to Mock an Exception Class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I've noticed that when you upgrade Spring Boot to at least 2.5.11, it seems that any exceptions that you mock such as

```java
@Mock
private MissingServletRequestParameterException missingServletRequestParameterException;
```

then try to actually use the mock in the following manner

```java
when(missingServletRequestParameterException.getParameterName()).thenReturn("Name");
when(missingServletRequestParameterException.getParameterType()).thenReturn("Type");
logger.error("An error has occurred: ", missingServletRequestParameterException);
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`.  The same piece of code above works fine up to Spring Boot 2.5.10.

However, given the fact that you could just create an Exception object, it doesn't seem that you would really need to mock Exception classes at all.  But maybe there are cases that you would need to do just that?

I'm not an expert with using mocking frameworks, so it would be nice to fill in that knowledge gap.

Comment: Maybe you have some special logic that occurs when the parameter name/type is "Name" and "Type"? I can't think of very many reasons you'd want to mock an exception. I also don't see any reason why you can't mock the exception in your example, and suspect it might just be misconfiguration of the test. I think this question is a little too broad/opinion based.

Comment: The `MissingServletRequestParameterException` is a Spring Web class.  The methods defined only return and name/type defined.  The logger is from Spring Boot's Logback 1.2.11 dependency.  It's interesting how only updating Spring Boot caused this mock to not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of mocking a class is so that you can remove any logic that the class has, and either replace it with your own logic, or eliminate it altogether.  Therefore, you should only EVER mock classes that have some kind of logic.  Mocking a class that's just got a bunch of fields, with getters and setters, is a waste of time.

Now, if your exception class has logic in it, then it's doing more than an exception class should.  You've violated the single responsibility principle.  Don't do that.

In short then, you should NEVER be mocking your exception classes.  If you think you need to, then it's a sure sign you've done something wrong.